# JQuery Clone div, search for specific id's and increment them

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone a div inside a form with several inputs in it.
Heres my html:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sf_action" value="INSERT" />
    <input type="text" name="sf_anzahl[2]" value="" placeholder="Anz." class="w50x TxtCenter" />
    <input type="text" name="sf_hoehe[2]" value="" placeholder="Höhe" class="w100x BorderLeft TxtCenter" />
    <input type="text" name="sf_breite[2]" value="" placeholder="Breite" class="w100x TxtCenter BorderLeft" />
    <select name="sf_art[2]" class="w150x BorderLeft">
    <option value="0">Automatiktür</option>
    <option value="1">Bürofenster</option>
    <option value="2">Shopfenster</option>
    <option value="3">Oberlichter</option>
    </select>&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rsi[2]" value="1" /> R-SI&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rssf[2]" value="1" /> R-SSF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rspf[2]" value="1" /> R-SPF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_ssf[2]" value="1" /> SSF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_upm[2]" value="1" /> UPM&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_ebm[2]" value="1" /> EBM&emsp;
</div>
<input type="button" class="add1" value="+" />
```

and my jquery:

```
$(".add1").on("click", function() 
{
    var eingabe = $(this).prev("div").clone();
    eingabe.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    eingabe.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
    var idar = $("input:nth-child(2n)", eingabe).attr("name").match(/\[(.*)\]/);
    var ausgabe = eingabe.prop('outerHTML');
    var id = parseInt(idar[1]);
    var ausgabeX = $(ausgabe).text().replace(/\[(.*)\]/, ++id);
    $(ausgabeX).insertBefore(this);
});
```

On "click" I want to clone the whole div and add it (before the button, after the last div).

The cloning itself just worked fine, but now I want to get the id inbetween the brackets [], increment it and replace it in the new div in all name attributes.

I can get the id and increment it, but can't figure out how to replace it in the new inputs.

I already get some divs from the database, so the id is not always [0], for example [1]-[4] can already exist. Especially for this case i need to increment the number in the brackets. Empty brackets won't work.

Comment: This is a pure JS (or rather, jQuery) question and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: There's no need write `name` as `sf[0]`, `sf[]` will do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select all elements having as attribute name a value like ***[number]*** you can use:

```
eingabe.find('[name*="["]')
```

and in order to increment this number by one you can:

```
eingabe.find('[name*="["]').attr('name', function (index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/^(.*\[)(\d)(\])$/, function () {
        return arguments[1] + (parseInt(arguments[2]) + 1) + arguments[3];
    });
});
```

For details see:

- [attribute-contains-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/): Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.
- [.attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function): A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.
- [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): str.replace(regexp, function)

The snippet:

```js
$(".add1").on("click", function (e) {
  var eingabe = $(this).prev("div").clone();
  eingabe.find("input[type='text']").val("");
  eingabe.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
  eingabe.find('[name*="["]').attr('name', function (index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/^(.*\[)(\d)(\])$/, function () {
      return arguments[1] + (parseInt(arguments[2]) + 1) + arguments[3];
    });
  });
  $(eingabe).insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sf_action" value="INSERT"/>
    <input type="text" name="sf_anzahl[0]" value="" placeholder="Anz." class="w50x TxtCenter"/>
    <input type="text" name="sf_hoehe[0]" value="" placeholder="Höhe" class="w100x BorderLeft TxtCenter"/>
    <input type="text" name="sf_breite[0]" value="" placeholder="Breite" class="w100x TxtCenter BorderLeft"/>
    <select name="sf_art[0]" class="w150x BorderLeft">
        <option value="0">Automatiktür</option>
        <option value="1">Bürofenster</option>
        <option value="2">Shopfenster</option>
        <option value="3">Oberlichter</option>
    </select>&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rsi[0]" value="1"/> R-SI&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rssf[0]" value="1"/> R-SSF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_rspf[0]" value="1"/> R-SPF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_ssf[0]" value="1"/> SSF&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_upm[0]" value="1"/> UPM&emsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="sf_ebm[0]" value="1"/> EBM&emsp;
</div>
<input type="button" class="add1" value="+"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine. Also thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily set a new id with:

```
$('#selector').attr('id', 'new_value');
```

Answer (score -1):

Markup like

```
<div>
    <input name="somename[0]" value="" class="" />
    <input name="someothername[0]" value="" class="" />
</div>
<div>
    <input name="somename[1]" value="" class="" />
    <input name="someothername[1]" value="" class="" />
</div>
```

is the same as this:

```
<div>
    <input name="somename[]" value="" class="" />
    <input name="someothername[]" value="" class="" />
</div>
<div>
    <input name="somename[]" value="" class="" />
    <input name="someothername[]" value="" class="" />
</div>
```

All values will be passed to server as zero-indexed arrays.
So, you can simplify your markup to:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sf_action" value="INSERT" />
    <input type="text" name="sf_anzahl[]" value="" placeholder="Anz." class="w50x TxtCenter" />
    <input type="text" name="sf_hoehe[]" value="" placeholder="Höhe" class="w100x BorderLeft TxtCenter" />
    <!-- more markup -->
```

And just clone div without using and incrementing value in brackets:

```
$(".add1").on("click", function() 
{
    var eingabe = $(this).prev("div").clone();
    eingabe.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    eingabe.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
    $(eingabe).insertBefore(this);
});
```

Comment: I'm curious. Is this really working? I tried and I got input names like `sf_anzahl[]` even on server.